# Instagram app narrow on iPad with iOS 12 update

Tags: ios, ipad

I updated my iPad mini 4 to iOS 12.  When I viewed my Instagram account it changed the size of the screen, made it narrow as though it is to be viewed on a phone. It's very annoying as I use this account a lot for my photographs. Can it be rectified, as when I contacted Apple they were unable to help, said they would notify the engineers at Apple. I reloaded Instagram and did a hard reset but to no avail.

Comment: Were you able to use the Instagram app all right on iOS 11? You can still rollback to iOS 11 on your iPad if you wish.

Comment: First I would remove and reinstall the app, then I would ask Instagram support (or their forums) if this is a known issue.

Comment: I'm not at all understanding why you'd start with contacting Apple about a third party app. Did you reach out to instragam support (facebook basically) and they directed you to Apple?

Comment: Thanks, but it coincided with when I updated to IOS 12, hence my contacting Apple.  I have removed and reinstalled Instagram and reported issue to them several times. I understand I can roll back to IOS 11 but looking online it seems complicated. R

Answer (score 1):

The Instagram app still hasn't turned on iPad sizing, and in iOS 11 the Instagram app would use the aspect ratio of the iPhone 8 (whether actual size or ‘zoomed’) but with iOS 12 the app is now iPhone X aspect ratio, with black bars on the left and right.

It doesn't look like there is a way to return to the previous aspect ratio, similar to how one of the iOS upgrades changed the aspect ratio from iPhone 4s to iPhone 5 on iPad in the past.

As iOS 12 has only just been released, you can still restore back to iOS 11, but I don't think an aspect ratio change to a single app is worth staying on an old iOS forever for.